# can i use multiple input model with sklearn(keras multiple input model)

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

I want to train multiple input keras model with sklearn cross validation feature. But i failed it. sklearn doesn't supprot multiple input model? Are there other way to overcome it?

These are input shapes

```
for sheet in tower_dataset :
    print sheet.shape
```

output

```
(126L, 3L)
(126L, 45L)
(126L, 148L)
(126L, 148L)
(126L, 148L)
(126L, 148L)
(126L, 148L)
(126L, 148L)
(126L, 148L)
(126L, 148L)
(126L, 100L)
(126L, 296L)
(126L, 296L)
(126L, 176L)
(126L, 31L)
(126L, 5L)
```

And What i tried to do is that train the keras model with sklearn cross validation.

```
epochs = 100
n_folds = 10
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10)
skf = StratifiedKFold(y=label, n_folds=n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=rand_seed)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(y=label, n_folds=n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=rand_seed)
```

error output

```
results = cross_val_score(model, tower_dataset, label, cv=kfold)
print(results.mean())
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-219-924ce2fda183> in <module>()
      6 kfold = StratifiedKFold(y=label, n_folds=n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=rand_seed)
      7 
----> 8 results = cross_val_score(model, tower_dataset, label, cv=kfold)
      9 print(results.mean())
     10 

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.pyc in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
   1420         Array of scores of the estimator for each run of the cross validation.
   1421     """
-> 1422     X, y = indexable(X, y)
   1423 
   1424     cv = check_cv(cv, X, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in indexable(*iterables)
    199         else:
    200             result.append(np.array(X))
--> 201     check_consistent_length(*result)
    202     return result
    203 

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    174     if len(uniques) > 1:
    175         raise ValueError("Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: "
--> 176                          "%s" % str(uniques))
    177 
    178 

ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 16 126]
```

thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Hey there. Did you figure this out?

Comment: It seems from [keras issue 2748](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2748) that this is not possible as of today